# How to position x AxesLabel below the axis with custom ticks?

Tags: plotting

Consider a simple plot with textual x ticks.

```
ListPlot[
 {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}},
 Ticks -> {Table[{i, (Characters@"ab")[[i]]}, {i, 2}], Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> {"character", "val"},
 PlotLegends -> {"r", "w"}
 ]
```

[image]

**How to place the x-axis label below the x axis?**

Note that several solutions to this popular question on SE suggest

- using `Frame` with `FrameLabel`. I tried this but it hides the ticks
- Using `Labeled`. It kind of works though the look and feel of the y axis label from `AxesLabel` and x axis label from `Labeled` differ.

I am open to using `Labeled` alone as long as the y axis label looks similar to x-axis' and is properly oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show how you tried to use `Frame` so it is unclear why you say it caused the label to hide the ticks. Perhaps you did not change `Ticks` to `FrameTicks`

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameTicks ->
  {Table[{i, (Characters@"abc")[[i]]}, {i, 3}], Automatic},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"character", "val"}),
 PlotLegends -> {"r", "w"},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: thnx...yeah i was using normal `Ticks`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `Labeled` for both labels:

```
Labeled[
 ListPlot[
  {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}},
  Ticks -> {Table[{i, (Characters@"ab")[[i]]}, {i, 2}], Automatic},
  PlotLegends -> {"r", "w"}
  ],
 {"character", "val"},
 {Bottom, {Top, Left}},
 LabelStyle -> {"Graphics", "GraphicsAxes", "GraphicsLabel"}
 ]
```

[image]

Using `Labeled` for both has of course the advantage that both labels look exactly the same, no matter how you style them. But since we can get the exact style used by the default labels, we can also specify the y-label using `AxesLabel`:

```
Labeled[
 ListPlot[
  {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}},
  Ticks -> {Table[{i, (Characters@"ab")[[i]]}, {i, 2}], Automatic},
  PlotLegends -> {"r", "w"},
  AxesLabel -> {"character", "val"}
  ],
 "character",
 Bottom,
 LabelStyle -> {"Graphics", "GraphicsAxes", "GraphicsLabel"}
 ]
```

Comment: thnx for the quick solve...simple&works.... can you please explain the meaning of  `LabelStyle -> {"Graphics", "GraphicsAxes", "GraphicsLabel"}`

Comment: Those refer to named styles as defined in the stylesheet (Format>Edit stylesheet>Click on Default.nb>Click on Core.nb>Search for "Graphics"). The fact that those are used is mentioned in [the documentation for `Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) in the second to last point in the details section. To find the exact combination of styles, I simply tried different combinations and modified the styles a bit too see what affects what.